# Change Text after onWindowFocusChange() has been called

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a fighting screen where I have two sprites, and on top of them I have health bars with their health points written (ProgressBar with a TextView on top of it).
I also have a AnimationDrawable. And it is started inside of onWindowsFocusChanged(). I want to have the text in front of the progressBar change after the animation. So, for example, before the animation a bar has 150/150 written and after the animation I want it to change to, for example, 80/150. The thing is, whenever I try to call setText, the app crashes (I guess because onWindowFocusChanged is the last thing that's called). Is there a way to do this?

Here's a snippet of my code (number_one.start() is the starting of the animation):

```
private void health_bars(int points_one, int points_two){

    healthBarOne.setMax(MAX_HEALTH);
    healthBarOne.setProgress(points_one);
    health_points_one.setText(points_one + "/" + MAX_HEALTH);

    healthBarTwo.setMax(MAX_HEALTH);
    healthBarTwo.setProgress(points_two);
    health_points_two.setText(points_two + "/" + MAX_HEALTH);

}




public void onWindowFocusChanged(final boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        Thread th = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                number_one.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                }
                health_bars(new_health_one, new_health_two);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                }
                finish();
            }
        };
        th.start();
        attackAnimation();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

EDIT:
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmgAl.jpg)

Comment: Share the error log...

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar It's on the post, last line (it's a print screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update UI elements from any other thread than UI. That is basically what the error is saying. To fix this, use runOnUiThread method in Android:

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        health_bars(new_health_one, new_health_two);
                    }
                });
       }
      }
```

Comment: This is the answer, I was going to post it, now I don't need to, this will work for sure +1.

Comment: I didn't check the errorLog, after Lalit told me to check it, I went to search that error lol!
Note to self: always check error log
Thanks guys